# What exactly happens in spring boot when I use @Service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I know that we used @Service for the business logic, but what exactly Spring do when he sees this annotation? Can someone please exaplain it, if possible with the example. F.ex when we write @Autoweired, it allows Spring to resolve and inject collaborating beans into our bean. Thanks In advance

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all as far as I know.
You can use @Component annotation as well on your service class and it will work fine. Spring will recognize and scan that for bean creation.

@Service annotation contains @Component in it, similar to the fact that @RestController has @Controller as part of it, but in controller theory, @RestController does bring some additional features ( @Controller + @ResponseBody = @RestController ).

Overall it's just good practice to annotate service classes with @Service, and persistence classes with @Repository ( @Repository does have additional features over @Component like transaction rollback ), but all these stereotype annotations contain @Component annotation for Spring to be able to scan them and register in Spring container for bean creation.

In my opinion, @Service is just used to make your code more readable and structured, but makes no difference if you would use @Component for your Service layer.